# Collect data points in a list into weekly groups?

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, date-and-time

Consider data of a format such as

```
data = {{{2002, 7, 30}, 1.20431}, {{2002, 7, 31}, 0.52822}, 
        {{2002, 8, 1}, -1.51937}, {{2002, 8, 2}, -1.2966},
        {{2002, 8, 5}, -1.97334}, {{2002, 8, 6}, 1.07311},
        {{2002, 8, 7}, 0.224605}, {{2002, 8, 8}, 1.78266},
        {{2002, 8, 9}, 0.90241}, {{2002, 8, 12}, 0.502187}};
```

I'd like to have a function that adds a dimension to the list and automatically collects all data points belonging to a single week together, e.g.:

```
weekly[data]
```

with output

```
 {
  {
    {{2002, 7, 30}, 1.20431}, {{2002, 7, 31}, 0.52822}, 
    {{2002, 8, 1}, -1.51937}, {{2002, 8, 2}, -1.2966}
  }
  ,
  {
    {{2002, 8, 5}, -1.97334}, {{2002, 8, 6}, 1.07311},
    {{2002, 8, 7}, 0.224605}, {{2002, 8, 8}, 1.78266},
    {{2002, 8, 9}, 0.90241}
  }
  ,
  {
    {{2002, 8, 12}, 0.502187}
  }
 };
```

> Is there a function in Mathematica that can do this? Or maybe one can implement it?

Comment: Convert to `DateObject`, sort, get the days of the week, split by whichever day you consider as starting your week (maybe `Monday`?),

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can `GatherBy` using  [`DateValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateValue.html) with `"Week"` (`{"Year","Week"}` if the input data spans multiple years) as date element as the second argument:

```
GatherBy[data, DateValue[#[[1]], "Week"] &]
```

> {{{{2002, 7, 30}, 1.20431}, {{2002, 7, 31}, 
>      0.52822}, {{2002, 8, 1}, -1.51937}, {{2002, 8, 
>       2}, -1.2966}},
>   {{{2002, 8, 5}, -1.97334}, {{2002, 8, 6}, 
>      1.07311}, {{2002, 8, 7}, 0.224605}, {{2002, 8, 8}, 
>      1.78266}, {{2002, 8, 9}, 0.90241}},
>   {{{2002, 8, 12}, 0.502187}}}

Answer (score 3):

Additionally, `CurrentDate` and `PreviousDate` work too. `CurrentDate` appears to be implemented in terms of `PreviousDate`. Of course, `NextDate` would also work.

```
GatherBy[data, CurrentDate[First[#], "Week"] &]
```

> {{{{2002, 7, 30}, 1.20431}, {{2002, 7, 31}, 
>      0.52822}, {{2002, 8, 1}, -1.51937}, {{2002, 8, 
>       2}, -1.2966}}, {{{2002, 8, 5}, -1.97334}, {{2002, 8, 6}, 
>      1.07311}, {{2002, 8, 7}, 0.224605}, {{2002, 8, 8}, 
>      1.78266}, {{2002, 8, 9}, 0.90241}}, {{{2002, 8, 12}, 0.502187}}}

```
GatherBy[data, PreviousDate[First[#], "Week"] &]
```